# WordPress show custom post type posts between normal post loop with pagination

Tags: php, wordpress

I am developing a WordPress website where I want to show posts based on some logic below:

On the front page, I want to show **10 posts** and then pagination **but** in **every 3 posts** I want to show another custom post type posts.

```
while ( have_posts() ) {
    the_post();
    the_title();
    the_content();
    echo '<hr/>';

   // Above will be shown 3 posts, 
   // then my custom post type post ( pro_event, special)
   // After that remaining 7 Posts

}
pagination();
```

How can I do this?

Shall I call the custom posts type posts code in between the while loop() or is there other way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with simple `if` statement:

```php
$shown_post_count = 0;
while ( have_posts() ) {
    if($shown_post_count != 3) {
        the_post();
        the_title();
        the_content();
    } else {
        // your custom post here
    }

    echo '<hr/>';
    $shown_post_count++;
}
pagination();
```

Hope this helps you